# How to create rooms with socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am writing an online lottery, I want to create different rooms with a limit on rates and participants. Question. How to implement the room?

Actually, here is the class of the GameController.js game:

```
class GameController {
    constructor (timer, minBetPrice, maxBetPrice, maxAmount, room, port, socket) {

        this.bets = {}
        this.users = {}
        this.room = room
        this.timer = timer
        this.minBetPrice = minBetPrice
        this.maxBetPrice = maxBetPrice
        this.maxAmount = maxAmount
        this.amount = null
        this.io = socket
        this.io.listen (port)
        this.initConnect ()

    }
    initConnect () {
        try {
            this.io.on ('connection', (socket => {
                this.users [socket.id] = {
                    id: socket.id
                }
                console.log (this.users)
                this.connectInRoom (socket)
                socket.on ('disconnect', data => {
                    console.log (`$ {socket.id} disconnected`)
                    delete this.users [socket.id]
                })
            }))
        } catch (e) {
            console.error (e)
        }
    }
    connectInRoom (socket) {
        socket.on ('event', data => {
            socket.join (data.room)
            console.log (`$ {socket.id} - Joined in $ {data.room} room`)
            socket.emit ('event', {
                success: true
                message: `UserID - $ {socket.id}`,
                room: data.room
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the contents of app.js:

```
const smallRoom = new GameController (10, 10, 20, 20, 'smallRoom', 4040, io)
const highRoom = new GameController (5, 0, 10, 20, 'highRoom', 4045, io)
```

From the client on the event event, I get the name of the room and connect to it. As far as I understand, do not need to create 2 instances of the class for different rooms in app.js? Because now I have 2 connections happening right away.

In the future, when creating a bet in a certain room, will I need to send a bet and the name of the room to which it will go?

Comment: You probably need to separate your gameplay code from your socket handling code.
For example:

- LobbyController: initializes socket io (many connections or single is your choice) and the multiple game rooms. knows about the messaging protocol and knows which action to perform at which room based on the messages it receives from clients.

- GameController: provides the interface of what is and can happen inside a game room. like: the joined users, max bet, user plays .etc

Comment: @AngelKyriako Do I need to create a class socket and inherit games from it? I understand correctly?